# STM32 link crc value of firmware in the final binary

Tags: stm32, bootloader, linker-scripts

I'm attempting to write a bootloader + application for a custom STM32F401RE board, and I have some questions.

Currently, I have the booloader lives at 0x08000000, and application lives 0x08020000. The idea is to have the bootloader perform a CRC check before jumping to the application.

I used a linker script to create a section called `.fw_crc` right after `.isr_vector` , and before `.text`. In the application code, I can write to this directly to this address in the flash. But this is where I got stuck.

If I understand it correctly, I should...

1. Default the CRC value to 0 in the application.
2. Build the binary.
3. Generate the CRC of this binary.
4. Use some hex tool to overwrite this section with the computed CRC value.
5. Regenerate the binary again for final flashing.

Is the above assumption correct? Doesn't regenerating the binary a second time with the updated CRC value ultimately change the resulting CRC of the final binary?

Also, inside the bootloader, do I perform the CRC check from the start of the `application_address` to `application_address + binary_size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the above assumption correct? Doesn't regenerating the binary a second time with the updated CRC value ultimately change the resulting CRC of the final binary?

- The default value of the CRC might be set to anything you like. It will be overwritten by your post-build process anyway.
- In your post-build step, you must calculate the CRC over the entire application binary except for the `.fw_crc`, and write the CRC result into that specific memory region. However, since the `.fw_crc` is defined in between the `.isr_vector` and `.text` regions, you should consider calculating the CRC for those two parts separately and combining them. A suggestion would be to re-arrange your memory areas such that `.fw_crc` lies at the start. For this to work, you have to relocate the ISR vector table in flash with the necessary offset. Then you will be able to calculate the application binary CRC more easily.

> Also, inside the bootloader, do I perform the CRC check from the start of the `application_address` to `application_address + binary_size`?

As mentioned earlier, according to your current memory arrangement, you will have to calculate the CRC over two memory regions i.e. `.isr_vector` and `.text`. Of course, you will need to perform the same CRC calculation and comparison inside the bootloader to verify the validity of your application binray.

Comment: you should not have been placing the CRC inside the image. It does not make any sense.

Comment: @P__J__ What is the problem with that? Where else would you place the CRC of the image binary?

Comment: the problem is : you first calculate the CRC without the CRC then with. Why?

Comment: @P__J__: I specifically pointed out this issue in my reply, i.e. the CRC-dedicated area must be excluded in CRC calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It and over complication of a very simple thing. Just after the interrupt vectors place the length of the image (linker script - simple add the lengths of the FLASH sections).

In the post-build operation calculate the CRC and append it to the bin image. When you flash the image simple do the CRC of the whole image (including the appended CRC at the end). The result should be 0.

Comment: >(linker script - simple add the lengths of the FLASH sections).


Does this mean the size of the binary will always be the max size of FLASH defined in the linker script?

Comment: @jdinh0608 ?. Actual size of the occupied FLASH. I wrote sections not regions

Answer (score 0):

*How to insert CRC of firmware in the middle of firmware*

*(without excluding of areas from calculation)*

```
.isr_begin
 ...
.isr_end

.fw_crc (uint32) = 0
.fw_crc_add (uint32) = 0

.text_begin
 ...
.text_end
```

1. Set **.fw_crc** and **.fw_crc_add** to 0x00000000U.
2. Calculate CRC32 over all firmware, from **.isr_begin** to **.text_end**. Its  a resulting CRC32.
3. Write resulting CRC32 to **.fw_crc** in binary/hex file.
4. Calculate CRC32 from **.isr_begin** to **.fw_crc** = **CRC_Before**. It is the intermediate CRC32 value at the time **.fw_crc** completion in the direct order of CRC32 calculation .
5. Calculate CRC32 from **.text_end** to **.text_begin** in **reversed order** = **CRC_After**. It is the intermediate CRC32 value at the start of the **.text_begin** in the usual order of the CRC32 calculation.

**CRC_Before** is known >>> ???**fw_crc_add**??? <<< **CRC_After** is known

6. Calculate what value must be inserted into **.fw_crc_add** in order to get the value of **CRC_After** from the value of **CRC_Before**.
7. Write **fw_crc_add** into binary/hex file.
8. Calculate CRC32 over all file to verify, that its CRC32 is equals to CRC32 from step 2.

See also

- riuson/crcrevrs on github
- projects/crcrevrs on sourceforge